# PHP Email is not being sent via PHPMailer at 000webhost

Tags: php, email, ssl

I have enabled less secure apps on my account but still the same `error`.
Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed
I tried with a free host 000webhost. Here is my code

```
<?php

require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

//$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'leets@gmail.com';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'private';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 465;                                    // TCP port to connect to

$mail->setFrom('leets@gmail.com', 'tEst');
$mail->addAddress('leets@gmail.com');     // Add a recipient
$mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional
$mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'Hello ,Click On the link to reset password</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
?>
```

Please Help.

Comment: What error you receive when script is executed?

Comment: " but still the same error" - What is the error?

Comment: Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed

Answer (score 1):

does changing to port 587 help?

```
smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
smtp.Port = 587;
```

Comment: Sorry that didn't work, I also adjusted the password for google two factor, you will need to setup an application specific password instead of your normal email account password.

Link for application specific password: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833

You have to set $mail->Password to your application specific password you created above.

Comment: Thanks.I got it working with localhost on wamp which means my gmail is ok..I believe the problem is from my host.